# How to tell if a text field has been changed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having a problem with a react component. It's supposed to test, whenever the field's value is changed, if the value on the field is different from the prop value, but once changed it seems to change the prop too.

```
 handleChange = (id, event) => {
    this.props.test(id, event.target.value)
    if (this.validate(event.target.value) || (event.target.value === "" && !this.props.required)) {
      this.setState({ valid: true })
      this.props.canSubmit(true)
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ valid: false })
      this.props.canSubmit(false)
    }
    if (event.target.value !== this.props.field_value) {
      this.setState({ changed: true })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ changed: false })
    }
render() {
    return (
      <div className="mb-3" >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
        />
        <span>
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="standard" type="text" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            value={this.props.field_value || ""}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(this.props.field_id, event)}
            label={this.props.field_label}
            error={!this.state.valid}
          />
          <Icon onClick={this.handleDescription} className="description">help_outlined</Icon>
          {this.state.changed ? <Icon>edit</Icon> : null}
        </span>
      </div>
```

I've also tried saving the prop value in a state, which also doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea?

Edit:

For more clarification, the problem I'm having is that the prop value is changed whenever the field value is changed, which means that once I change the value in the field, it's always going to think it's different from the original value. For exemple: let's say an email field has a default value of "a@a.com", then I change it to "b@a.com". Now it says it's different, and it's correct. The problem
is when I change it back to "a@a.com", now it considers the prop value as the former "b@a.com" and therefore thinks its different even tho it's the same.

Comment: you have set it to a flag `changed` right? that itself will tell you whther ur text field had value or not

Comment: I don't want to know if it has a value. I want to know if the user has changed the value that comes by default as a prop.

Comment: yes. exactly. flag is set as in you have set it as `true` which means you have some value in it, if its `false` then it means you do not have value in it.

Comment: How are you setting the prop value of `field_value` in the parent component, is it a hardcoded string or a dynamic value? Also could you share the code of `test` function to gain more context of the exact issue.

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni `field_value` is a dynamic value fetched by the parent component from a server. The `test()` function changes the state on the parent component, effectively binding the two values. My problem is exactly in there, when one value changes, so does the other, so I don't have direct access to the original value to compare.

Comment: Do you mean that you are updating the state in the parent component, received via the callback, which in turn is set on the `field_value` prop after initially it's fetched from the server? If that's the case, why'd you want to update the state in the parent component, if you want to test it against a default value? It'd be better if you could let us have a look into the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You have set flag which is set to true/false in your code, which itself tells you whether or not you have anything in your text field or not. The flag does not tell you what value you have in the text field.

So, it will be something like code below if its what your searching for:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

class MainPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: "",
            subtitle: "",
            flag: false,
        };
    }
    handleFilterChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        if (this.state.title || this.state.subtitle) {
            this.setState({ flag: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ flag: false });
        }
    };

    fetchOrdersByQuery = async () => {
        //code for search
    }

    resetFilter = async () => {
        this.setState({
            head: "",
            subhead: "",
            flag: false,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        margin="dense"
                        name="title"
                        label="Title"
                        value={this.state.title}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        margin="dense"
                        name="subtitle"
                        label="Sub-Title"
                        value={this.state.subtitle}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        margin="normal"
                        onClick={this.resetFilter}
                    >
                        {" "}
                        Reset
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        margin="normal"
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={this.fetchOrdersByQuery}
                    >
                        Search
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}


export default (MainPage);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not really what I'm looking for. The problem I'm having is that the prop value is changed whenever the field value is changed, which means that once I change the value in the field, it's always going to think it's different from the original value. For exemple: let's say an email field has a default value of "a@a.com", then I change it to "b@a.com". Now it says it's different, and it's correct. The problem 
is when I change it back to "a@a.com", now it considers the prop value as the former "b@a.com" and therefore thinks its different even tho it's the same.